# Why is this program indiscriminately adding members to the set memsSet?

Tags: java, treeset

I cannot figure out why the second for loop built around pacs.length keeps adding elements to the set even though they do not contain the variable being searched for in the mems.contains.  I cannot get the
code to
not add members to the set indiscriminately.  I do not see where I am going wrong, obviously.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Trubl
{
public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader pacsFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "pacs.txt" ) );
    BufferedReader membersFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "members.txt" ) );

    TreeSet<String> memsSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>> pac2mems = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>();

    String[] pacs = new String [9];

    int cnt = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < pacs.length; i++)
    {
        String pac = pacsFile.readLine();

        pacs[i] = pac;
    }

    pacsFile.close();

    Arrays.sort(pacs);

    int j = 0;

    while (membersFile.ready())
    {
        String mems = membersFile.readLine();
        System.out.println(mems);
        String[] splitter = mems.split("\\s+");

        for (int i = 1; i < pacs.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(pacs[i]);
            if (mems.contains(pacs[i]))
            {
                memsSet.add(splitter[0]);
            }
            System.out.println(memsSet);

        }



        pac2mems.put(pacs[j], memsSet);
        j++;
    }

    membersFile.close();

    for (cnt = 0; cnt < pac2mems.size(); cnt++)
        System.out.println(pacs[cnt] + " " + pac2mems.get(pacs[cnt]));

} // END MAIN
```

}

Comment: _" I cannot get the code to not add members to the set indiscriminately"_  -- what does this mean?  You will have to provide some examples demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mems.contains(pacs[i]))
{
  memsSet.add(splitter[0]);
}
```

This adds to memsSet if mems does contain the string. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, but that is not what is happening when i run the program

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier to answer if you provided an example of what is happening, i.e. example input files and resulting output.

However, I am going to take a wild guess anyway. If your "pacsFile" has an empty line in it, there will be an element which is an empty string and in that case there will always be an `i` for which `mems.contains(pacs[i])` is true (a String always `contains` the empty string).